# How to install Logiks Framework

Tags: php

I am trying to install Logiks framework on my dev server. I am using my laptop for development purpose with MacOS. What is the process for the same?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Installing Logiks is very easy, follow the guide at https://github.com/Logiks/Logiks-Installer-Cli to install it on your laptop.

Pre Requisites:

- Apache2 Server with PHP7.2 installed
- MySQL DB Server installed

You can also use docker to directly install and run your logiks instance. Details can be found here : https://github.com/Logiks/Logiks-Docker